# Question about OLE Files

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

Are the open format files that are saved with LibreOffice and OpenOffice act like the OLE files that are saved with MS Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No.

They may transport the same visuals and formats like when they were saved with MS Office, but they may not be 100% compatible at the end.

They are preferable if you are thinking of long term storage or sharing in an open-source-aware ecosystem, but do not share them if you deal with MS-only shops.

For example, I have to endure headhunters that *always* ask for CV's and resumes in some MS-Word-Format. I prepare and archive such documents in LibreOffice but export and send them as PDF. They never complain.